# VS2010 web performance test/Load test stopped working after installing VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

My web performance/load test has been working fine in VS2010 until yesterday when I installed VS2013.  I didn't upgrade my project/solution file. I am still trying to run my tests within VS2010.

When I am trying to run webtest locally, I got the following error:

```
Request failed: Exception occurred: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestCaseVariation.ProcessTransactionStarting(String transactionName, Boolean isForIncludedWebTest, Int32 declarativeWebTestItemId, Guid sourceWebTestId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.WebTest.BeginTransaction(String transactionName, Boolean isForIncludedWebTest, Int32 declarativeWebTestItemId, Guid sourceWebTestId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.WebTest.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.DeclarativeWebTest.<EnumerateRequests>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestCaseVariation.ExecuteNextTopLevelRequest()
```

I can run the test without an issue remotely though(my test controller is vs2010)

I can also run load test remotely, but got the following error thus not able to see the test results:

```
Exception   LoadTestException   1   Results collection stopped due to the following error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTest, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

my projects are still referencing version 10.0.0.0 dlls,auto redirected by Visual Studio to the ones under vs2013 installation folder though, not sure why it's trying to load version 12.0.0.0

Much appreciate for any help.

Comment: The Microsoft test assembly referenced in your project might be outdated since you upgraded Visual Studio. Maybe try deleting those references from your project and finding the updated ones in the new VS installation directory?

Comment: Actually tried both with no luck.  I can see from my property window that the reference are pointing to new location:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestFramework.dll  and the version NO. is 10.0.0.0

Comment: Did you have 2010 Premium and which flavor of VS 2013 did you install, e.g. VS 2013 Professional, Premium, Ultimate?

Comment: Ultimate.  I just got it fixed by installing the latest VS2013 update. seems that's the cause

Comment: Actually, it only fixed the load test issue. I am now able to run load test remotely without an issue.  However still facing the exception when try to  run web performance test with local settings.